# Replace NA in all columns of a dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

The question [replace NA in a dplyr chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714867/replace-na-in-a-dplyr-chain) results into the solution

```
dt %.% group_by(a) %.% mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(b), mean(b, na.rm = T), b))
```

with dplyr. I want to impute all colums with dplyr chain. There is no single column to group by, rather I want all numeric columns to have all NAs replaced by the means such as column means.

**What is the most elegant way to replace all NAs with column means with tidyverse/dp?**

Comment: Use `dt %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .))`   If you want elegance, then `dt %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate_all(zoo::na.aggregate)`

Comment: @akrun what about if you continue with long dplyr chain after the `group_by(a)`? And what is the `a`? Do you have to use `ungroup` after the `group_by`?

Comment: It depends on the operation you want afterwards.  Sometimes, I use `ungroup` because `spread` etc may not work with group columns

Comment: If you are using `rowwise` sum use the `rowSums` i.e. `%>% ungroup %>% mutate(newSum = rowSums(.[columnsofinterest]))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [na.locf using group\_by from dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212308/na-locf-using-group-by-from-dplyr)

Comment: It would be useful for downvoters to explain their votes so I could clarify the question as needed. I thank akrun for the answer where the `zoo::na.aggregate()` works very well :)

Comment: Related: [*Handle Continous Missing values in time-series data*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32694313/2204410)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `mutate_all` with `ifelse`

```
dt %>%
   group_by(a) %>% 
   mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .)))
```

---

If we want a compact option, then use the `na.aggregate` from `zoo` which by `default` replace `NA` values with `mean`

```
dt %>% 
   group_by(a) %>% 
   mutate_all(zoo::na.aggregate)
```

---

If we don't have a grouping variable, then remove the `group_by` and use `mutate_if` (just to be cautious about having some non-numeric column)

```
dt %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, zoo::na.aggregate)
```

If all the columns are numeric, even

```
zoo::na.aggregate(dt)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.frame(a = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
                 b= sample(c(NA, 1:5), 9, replace = TRUE), 
                 c = sample(c(NA, 1:3), 9, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: @hhh The `a` is from your code only..  If you have a different grouping variable, use that one

Comment: @hhh Isn't that just a row number column?  I thought you wanted to group by some column and then do the replacement based on it

Comment: @hhh If it is a row number, it is just a unique element.  So, You don't need any `group_by`, just do `dt %>% mutate_all(zoo::na.aggregate))`  or apply the `zoo::na.aggregate(dt)` on the entire dataset

Comment: Thank you, they worked `zoo::na.aggregate(data.frame(a=c(1,2,NaN),b=c(10,NaN,12)))` and `data.frame(a=c(1,2,NaN),b=c(10,NaN,12)) %>% zoo::na.aggregate()`.